# html 5 geolocation returns 0,0 on blackberry

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry

I've developed a web app that uses location detection, which works fine with Android, iPhone, and many desktop browsers; however, **the latitude and longitude values are always returned as 0,0 on my blackberry**.  It is running OS 6 (it reports 6.0.0.415).  Initially I was using google gears (the geo.js script), but after googling for a while I learned that gears doesn't support OS 6 (it only supports up to OS 5).  So after doing more research I learned that OS 6 should just work with the standard HTML5 Geolocation API.  However, this does not appear to be the case for me.  I tried the code shown on this page, but the latitude and longitude still returns as 0,0. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-HTML5-Geolocation-in-your-Web-or-BlackBerry-WebWorks/ta-p/630406

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've now realized that if I first tickle the device to activate the GPS (e.g. via something like Google Maps), the code will work. But if you DON'T do this, you'll get 0,0 as your lat,long from javascript, no matter where you are. After awakening the device's GPS via something besides the browser (again, e.g. GMaps), you'll get legitimate values. (found this here: http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-legacy-device-discussion/23544-7130e-gps-location-based-services.html) Any ideas?

Comment: By "any ideas" I mean, is there a way to get the proper coordinates without first launching another application?